# Load an image from media library onto canvas with WriteableBitmap image?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am trying to load a picture selected from media library of windows phone and I have done upto choosing the required picture and I am unable to load image onto my canvas named area with this code :

```
void photochoosertask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        WriteableBitmap bitMap = new WriteableBitmap(200,200);
        Extensions.LoadJpeg(bitMap, e.ChosenPhoto);
        Canvas.SetLeft(area, 10);
        Canvas.SetTop(area, 10);
        bitMap.Render(area, null);
        bitMap.Invalidate();
    }
}
```

But I am unable to do with this code..any suggestions..??
or how to do this task ? Is this the correct way ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
{
    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
    bi.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
    WriteableBitmap b = new WriteableBitmap(bi);
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = b;           
    Canvas.SetLeft(img, 10);
    Canvas.SetTop(img, 10);
    area.Children.Add(img);    
}
```

Comment: where does this "area" come from?

Comment: It was my Canvas name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to show the bitmap in your Canvas you would have to add an [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms610982%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control to its `Children` collection, which uses the bitmap as its [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.image.source%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

```
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap(200, 200);
Extensions.LoadJpeg(bitmap, e.ChosenPhoto);

var image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmap;

Canvas.SetLeft(image, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(image, 10);
area.Children.Add(image);
```

---

As `e.ChosenPhoto` is a stream, you may perhaps also use a [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of a WriteableBitmap, and set its source stream to `e.ChosenPhoto`. You may then set the size of the Image control to the desired values.

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosePhoto);

var image = new Image();
image.Source = bitmap;
image.Width = 200;
image.Height = 200;

Canvas.SetLeft(image, 10);
Canvas.SetTop(image, 10);
area.Children.Add(image);
```